# React Native convert SVG to PNG?

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, expo

I am trying to make an app where the user has to draw something, then I use that drawing and Tensorflow to detect the shapes. I managed to make a Drawing canvas with PanGestureHandler, View, Svg and Path, but now I want to convert this canvas to PNG (base64 blob). I have a function which converts every point to *svg d*, so my plan was to have a svg begin and end like this:

```
this.svgBegin = `<svg height="210" fill="red" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="400" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path fill="red" d="`
this.svgEnd = `"/></svg>`
```

and between them the points, so I kinda fake the conversion from react-native-svg to a xml svg. Btw, my render part looks like this:

```
return (
        <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={this._onPanGestureEvent}>
            <View style={{width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight - 100, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            <Svg width={windowWidth} fill={"#FFF"} height={windowHeight-100}
          >
          <G>
            <Path
                // key={this.state.previousStrokes.length}
                d={this.pointsToSvg(this.state.vector)}
                stroke={"#000"}
                strokeWidth={4}
                fill="none"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                
              />
          </G>
        </Svg>
        <Button title={"Clear"} onPress={() => this.hide()} />
        <Button title={"Export"} onPress={() => this.exportBase()} />

            </View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    );
```

The problem is that nothing seems to work. I send that svg string that i build to another  and pass it to xml={} prop, then by using a reference, I do something like this:

```
this.pathRef.current.toDataURL(data => { ... play with data } )
```

And pass the blob to a Image component to see the result (anyway I don't need to display it, i just want to check that the output image is what I just draw).

Am I doing things wrong? I think there is something wrong with react-native-svg/Svg component. When I export my face xml svg to a real file and open it in the browser, it's exactly what I just draw on my self-made canvas. Btw, I'm using Expo.
Thank you!

Comment: I think best way is to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-shot  library. Copy final drawing and render it inside viewshot and capture it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Imma take a look right now. Somehow I solved it, it was a problem with my reference (I had a lot of references in my component and I was kinda lost in them). Thanks once again

Comment: Can you post what your actual solution was? I'm trying to do the same thing. How did you set up the ref?